# Find vector coordinates with this information?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have this single linear algebra problem thats struggling me. I have to find the following vector coordinates:

A = λ1E1 + λ2E2 + … + λnEn

With this following information, this is the part I dont understand what does that data represents and how can I get the vector coordinates with it:

If in R':

E1 = (1,0,0,…,0)

E2 = (0,1,0,…,0)

……………………….

En = (0,0,0,…,1)

Can anyone give me a clue of where to start? Thanks.

Comment: Huh? So $A$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector, correct? Then certainly there exists unique $\lambda_i\in\Bbb R$ such that $A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_ie_i$ as the $e_i$'s are a basis for the vector space. But without further information, one cannot determine the scalars $\lambda_i$.

Comment: I cannot determine the scalars, but the vector coordinates?

Comment: The vector coordinates are precisely the scalars $\lambda_i$, assuming we are referring to the standard basis when talking about "vector coordinates" (as a vector's "coordinates" refers to a specific basis). That is, if $A=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ then $a_i=\lambda_i$ for each $i$. If this is all you want then great, but without further information about $A$ we cannot narrow this down really any more.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a little clearer:

$$
A=\lambda_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
+\lambda_2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
+ ... 
+\lambda_n \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \vdots\\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix}
$$

Ced

Answer (score 0):

Simply $A=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\\vdots\\\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$.